# Rearranging an equation with the sine function in it

Tags: equation-solving

When I evaluate `Solve[a==Sin[b*c], b]` to rearrange the following for $ b $:

$$ a = \sin(bc) $$

I get the following result from Mathematica:

$$\begin{align*} \left\{\left\{b\to \text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\frac{-\sin ^{-1}(a)+2 \pi  c_1+\pi }{c},c_1\in \mathbb{Z}\right]\right\},\right.\left.\left\{b\to \text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\frac{\sin ^{-1}(a)+2 \pi  c_1}{c},c_1\in \mathbb{Z}\right]\right\}\right\} \end{align*}$$

It seems far too complicated. Unless I'm making a huge mistake, surely solving the equation for $ b $ would give:

$$ b = \frac{\sin ^{-1}(a)}{c} $$

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is one possibility. But how about `b = (ArcSin[a] + 2 Pi)/c`? If you plug that into your defining equation then you get $a$ also.. so there are many answers, that's what Mathematica is telling you.

For example let

```
b = (ArcSin[a] + 2 Pi)/c
```

then calculate

```
Sin[b c]
```

and the answer is:

```
a
```

Similarly for other multiples of Pi.

Comment: Ah, I see. It looks like I've got a lot of learning ahead of me if I'm going to be able to make the most of Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a complete solution - and I think it is beautiful:

```
Reduce[a == Sin[b*c], b, Reals] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

The above is a bit closer to what you want - but is "correct".